# Insert into MySQL table if no row added within 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains a column consisting of timestamps.  I want to check if there is a new row within 5 minutes period of time.  If not, then insert a new row or update the last row status column.

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET status = 'offline'
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > ((SELECT MAX(dateandtime)) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

or insert into ... but no success so far. I'm using PHP in WordPress if that matters.

Comment: you say "insert a new row or update"; when do you want a new row and when do you want to update?  if updating, how do you decide which row to update?

Comment: I want to check the last row time, if in last five minutes, no new row added, I want to update the last row status or  I can insert a new row with the new status.

Comment: what does `select version();`show?

Comment: it shows 5.7.30-cll-lve

Comment: so if the last timestamp is more than 5 minutes ago, insert a new row, and otherwise just update the max timestamp row?  do you want to update just its status or also its timestamp to now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you. If you want to add new row, you need to use `INSERT` command with selection like this...

```
INSERT INTO sessions(user_id, last_visit)
SELECT 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM sessions
      WHERE user_id = 1
      HAVING (MAX(last_visit) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you want to update `status` column, you need to use simple `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE sessions
SET status = 'offline'
WHERE (last_visit + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Btw, you just need to have a `last_visit` column, and if it's less than now + 5 min, you already know that the user is offline. And you have to update this value on every authorized request with simple update like.

```
update users set last_visit = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where id = ?;
```

So your User class will be have a function `getStatus()` like this:

```
public function getStatus() {
    if ($this->lastVisit < (Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5))) {
        return 'offline';
    }    
    return 'online';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an auto-increment primary key, you can do this with `replace`:

```
replace into foo (id,dateandtime,status) values (
    (select id from foo f where dateandtime > now()-interval 5 minute order by dateandtime desc limit 1),
    now(),
    # or if you want to preserve the current timestamp, replace the previous now() with:
    #coalesce((select max(dateandtime) from foo f where dateandtime > now()-interval 5 minute), now()),
    'offline'
);
```

This tries to find the id of the row to update, or uses null to trigger a new auto-increment id to be generated.

Note that `replace` is unsafe (may cause the source and replica to diverge) when using statement-based replication; in that case you would need a stored procedure, or in your code (in a transaction, to prevent a race condition) to do an update, and only if it updated 0 rows, do an insert.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1c4b77145e53f8d781dd94e06d6e28bd) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=40adf47e87641b2b88dbedbfd80e0298)